# Gathering information from few forms in django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, formset

I am creating simple search engine, so I have one input text field on the top of the page and buttom "search" next to it. That is all in one form, and "produce" for instance`/q=search%20query`.

In sidebar I have panel with another form with filters, lets say `from`, `to`. I want to have a possibility of creating link like `/q=search%20query&from=20&to=50`. I wonder how button from first form should gather information from second form.

I read somewhere that there is something like formsets, however I didn't find information that they can be used to something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be most easily solved by making a form which includes both the search term and any filters; you can place the form elements wherever you want.

Your form would have to be something like:

```
from django import forms

    class MySearchForm(forms.Form):
        FILTERS = (("lt20", "Less than 20"),
                    ("20to50", "Twenty to fifty"),
                  )
        term = forms.CharField()
        filters = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget = CheckBoxSelectMultiple, choices = FILTERS)
```

Then you would have to display the form manually, so you can split it up however you want in the template. In other words, instead of using a filter like {{form.as_p}}, you would have to do `{{form.term}}` and `{{form.filters}}`.

You could also define your filters in a model, so that you can more easily change them, add to them, etc, st:

```
# in models.py
class = Filters(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

# in your form definition,
from your_app_name.models import Filters

class MySearchForm(forms.Form):
    term = forms.CharField()
    filters = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = Filters.objects.all(), widget = CheckBoxSelectMultiple)
```

Comment: both of my forms are in different files. To do what you suggest I have to merge them, and create a huge form containing a lot of other html elements between them.

Comment: You can place both forms in your template, as long as they are inside the same `<form>` tag, by adding a prefix to them. See [the docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/forms/api/#prefixes-for-forms). Another option would be to make a _third_ form which subclasses both of them, like so: `class MyBigForm(Form1, Form2):`

Answer (score 0):

I just come up with an idea, that I can create in first form additional hidden fields, which can be synchronized with fields from second form by JavaScript. This will create small redundancy, however seems to be very easy to implement.

Is it a good idea?

Comment: Sure, that would work. It would be clearer (and less prone to break) if instead you define a third form which subclasses both forms, which would inherit all of the fields.